# how to add records from DataTable to ArrayList using AddRange Method

Tags: asp.net, datatable, arraylist

Hey guys,
i have a dataTable, which contains a column which has 100 rows, now i want to add those rows in ArrayList, but not with the Add Method, because i have to use for loop for adding records one by one, so i want to prefer addrange method of arraylist, so it is possible to add records in arraylist from DataTable using AddRange.

Below is the code which i am using.

```
Dim adapGetImages As New SqlDataAdapter("select distinct FileName from Files where Filename<>'' and (RIGHT(FileName,3) = 'gif' or RIGHT(FileName,3) = 'jpg' or RIGHT(FileName,3) = 'bmp') order by FileName", connection)
Dim dtGetImages As New DataTable()
adapGetImages.Fill(dtGetImages)
ArrayList1.AddRange(dtGetImages.Rows[0][0].ToString())
```

The last line is where i am stuck. as if i run this it will just add single row, and if i say `dtGetImages.Rows.ToString()` then this will just Add System.DataRow in Arraylist and not its content.

Please reply what could be done for resolving this issue without any loops.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you wanting the values of a specific column in the row to be put in the ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
ArrayList1.AddRange(dtGetImages.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().[Select](Function(r) r(0).ToString()).ToArray())
```

#### Update

There are a few concepts at work here. First of all, you're not trying to add the *rows* to the list, but rather the first value in each row. As you mentioned, you could use a `for` loop to get this value out of each row and add it to a list, but loops like that aren't very concise or declarative. This is why we have LINQ (Language-Integrated Queries): a framework that simplifies the transformation of collections of values.

The `Select` method is an extension method defined in the LINQ framework. It takes as an argument a function that defines what transformation to perform on each item in the given collection. When the result of the `Select` is invoked, the given function is performed on each value, producing a new collection based on the results. Here we give it the function:

```
Function(r) r(0).ToString()
```

..., which tells it:

> Given a variable `r`, get the zeroth index of `r` and call `ToString()` on the result.

So if this `Select` method is called on an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, the resulting collection will be an `IEnumerable<string>`. Since the `ArrayList.AddRange` method requires an `ICollection`, we have to change our `IEnumerable<string>` into something that implements `ICollection`. As it turns out, arrays implement `ICollection`, so we can use the `ToArray()` method from LINQ to convert it into a value that `ArrayList.AddRange` will accept.

There's just one problem: the DataTable class was written before generics were part of the .NET framework, so the `DataRowCollection` class implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface rather than the strongly-typed `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Since our `Select` method needs to start with an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, we have to do something to convert `dtGetImages.Rows` into a `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. The `Cast` method, also provided by LINQ, will do this for us. We tell `Cast` that we happen to know that everything in the given `IEnumerable` (the `DataRowCollection` in this case) is going to be a `DataRow`, so it can safely cast each item into a `DataRow`, leaving us with the `IEnumerable<DataRow>` that we need to use the `Select` method on.

Hopefully that explains things pretty well. One thing you should be aware of is that this doesn't eliminate the use of loops. When you call `.ToArray()`, it pulls items from the `.Select`, which pulls items from the `.Cast`, which iterates over `dtGetImages.Rows` the same as if you'd written a `for` loop to populate an array. The only difference is that LINQ makes your code more declarative. It's the difference between saying:

> For each DataRow in the Rows property of this DataTable, I'm going to create a variable called `row`. Then I will call `ToString` on the zeroth element of this variable and add the result to the ArrayList.

... and saying:

> I am calling `ToString` on the zeroth element out of each DataRow in the Rows property of this DataTable, and adding the results to the ArrayList.

They both mean roughly the same thing, but one is both clearer and more concise.

Comment: @Stripling: i checked out the code which you have gave, but i got an error saying, there is nothing like Rows in Rows... can you please check and repost the code.... thanks for replying.

Comment: @Abbas: Sorry, I had `.Rows.Rows`. Try it now.

Comment: @Stripling: there is also nothing like Rows.Cast... Please check it out and reply soon

Comment: @Abbas: Yes there is. It's part of the LINQ framework, so you need to add `Imports System.Linq` at the top of your file.

Comment: @Stripling: thanks dude for your code, it worked, but if you dont mind, can you please explain me the concept behind this... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx) for the Fill method has this note:

> When handling batch SQL statements that return multiple results, the implementation of Fill and FillSchema for a .NET Framework data provider retrieves schema information for only the first result.

Are you getting the schema information for the first result?